# Should I absolutely avoid prop passing while using redux with reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Okay so after a month or two of learning ReactJs, I finally realised the need of using redux. Turns out the apps that I was building had too much prop drilled into the components, and I realized I needed something to makes states available globally among multiple components. I went straight to redux.

As a slow person, I found redux very hard to understand. But now I feel like I have a bit of grasp of it.
Take a look at the menu component that is in my app:

```js
export default function Menu(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.productStates.products);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products").then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PRODUCTS", data});
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <ProductDetails />
      <div className="menu">
        {products.map((product) => {
          return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );

}
```

The question I wanna ask is, am I doing it right by passing product as a prop to my `Product` component. Like is this the standard way of doing stuff like this. If I'm only passing prop to the only direct child, it's not props drilling is it?

Comment: Your code is fine but in my opinion, you should move the code related to the HTTP request from the `useEffect` hook into an async action creator (see: [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)). `useEffect` hook should just dispatch an action to start fetching the products.

Comment: Why use redux thunk? Why would I want to keep that inside that? And what is an async action creator?

Comment: [Why do i need redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct. If you want to understand when exactly to use Redux and when to stick to passing props, read this FAQ on Redux: https://redux.js.org/faq/general